# How do I call "put" on a WeakHashMap in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, weakhashmap

I created a `WeakHashMap` in Kotlin and for some reason, I am unable to call `put` it, it won't resolve.

```
val dataMap: Map<Int, MyData> = WeakHashMap<Int, MyData>()
dataMap.put(myInt, myData) // doesn't resolve
```

Is there a Kotlin equivalent for a `WeakHashMap`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have cast your WeakHashMap to a read-only Map, so you have restricted it to not have a `put` function. You should make the variable type MutableMap or leave it as a WeakHashMap.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Tenfour04. Removing the type of the dataMap resolved the issue (no longer programmed to interface but made to be of type WeakHashMap.

```
val dataMap = WeakHashMap<Int, MyData>()
styleDataMap.put(myInt, myData)
```

Comment: You could still program to the interface by using the type `MutableMap<…>` (which has the `put()` method) instead of `Map<…>` (which doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

The `put` is defined in `WeakHashMap` but not directly in `Map` itself. Values of a Map are read-only hence it prevents using any `put` method there. you can either use reference of `WeakHashMap` or you can convert to a `MutableMap` to call `put`

```
  val styleDataMap: WeakHashMap<Int, MyData> = WeakHashMap<Int, MyData>()
  styleDataMap.put(myInt, myData)
```

or

```
  val styleDataMap: Map<Int, MyData> = WeakHashMap<Int, MyData>()
  styleDataMap.toMutableMap().put(myInt, myData) // doesn't resolve
```

Comment: styleDataMap.toMutableMap() is not a good solution, because at every call it will create a new mutable map object